# Replace dataframe values with labels from a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, data-dictionary

I have a dataframe like this (simplified example)

DF1

```
id q1 q2_1  q2_2 
1  1  1     1  
2  1  2     2
3  2  3     3
4  2  3     3
5  1  1     3
```

and a dataframe with corresponding values like this

DF2

```
var  num  val
q1   1    male
q1   2    female
q2   1    one
q2   2    two
q2   3    three
```

What I would like its to replace values in the df1 with corresponding values from df2 to get DF3

DF3

```
id q1      q2_1    q2_2 
1  male    one     one  
2  male    two     two
3  female  three   three
4  female  three   three
5  male    one     three
```

Comment: DF1 has num column to be `1,1,2,2,1`. Based on what i understand, the corresponding q1 in DF3 should be `male, male, female, female, male`. Why is the last row of q1 in DF3 having female when the last row of q1 of DF1 is 1? Was it a typo?

Comment: corrected the typo

Comment: So `df1` = **encoded categorical values**, and `df2` = **data dictionary**, i.e. the label corresponding to each categorical level, for each question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to convert the df2 values into dictionary and use map to replace df1 values. Here's how I did it.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'q1':[1,1,2,2,1],'q2_1':[1,2,3,3,1],'q2_2':[1,2,3,3,3]})
print (df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var':['q1','q1','q2','q2','q2'],
                    'num':[1,2,1,2,3],
                    'val':['male','female','one','two','three']})

print (df2)

#create a slice of q1 and q2
q1 = df2.loc[df2['var'] == 'q1'][['num','val']]
q2 = df2.loc[df2['var'] == 'q2'][['num','val']]

#convert q1 and q2 to dicts
x = dict(zip(q1.num,q1.val))
y = dict(zip(q2.num,q2.val))

#use map to convert value using x and y
df1['q1'] = df1['q1'].map(x)
df1['q2_1'] = df1['q2_1'].map(y)
df1['q2_2'] = df1['q2_2'].map(y)
print (df1)
```

df1:

```
   q1  q2_1  q2_2
0   1     1     1
1   1     2     2
2   2     3     3
3   2     3     3
4   1     1     3
```

df2:

```
  var  num     val
0  q1    1    male
1  q1    2  female
2  q2    1     one
3  q2    2     two
4  q2    3   three
```

df1 after update:

```
       q1   q2_1   q2_2
0    male    one    one
1    male    two    two
2  female  three  three
3  female  three  three
4    male    one  three
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pandas import DataFrame as df

DF1=df({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'q1': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1], 'q2_1': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1], 'q2_2': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
DF2=df({'var': ['q1', 'q1', 'q2', 'q2', 'q2'], 'num': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'val': ['male', 'female', 'one', 'two', 'three']})

DF3 = DF1[:]
mapping_df_q1 = DF2[DF2['var']=='q1'][['num','val']]
mapping_dictionary_q1 = dict(zip(mapping_df_q1['num'],mapping_df_q1['val']))
DF3['q1'] = DF3['q1'].map(mapping_dictionary_q1)

mapping_df_q2 = DF2[DF2['var']=='q2'][['num','val']]
mapping_dictionary_q2 = dict(zip(mapping_df_q2['num'],mapping_df_q2['val']))
DF3['q2_1'] = DF3['q2_1'].map(mapping_dictionary_q2)
DF3['q2_2'] = DF3['q2_2'].map(mapping_dictionary_q2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So `df1` = encoded categorical values, and `df2` = data dictionary, i.e. the label corresponding to each categorical level, for each question. (Personally I strongly recommend you rename them `dv` and `dd` to avoid severe confusion, otherwise the numbers '1' and '2' have three diffent meanings, but anyway).

So for each of the individual data columns where 'col' is `df1['q1'], df1['q2_1'], df1['q2_2']`, we can do either of:

1. use `df1[col].map(...)`, if we pass it a dictionary for 'q1' where keys = categorical levels, values = categorical labels.
2. **use `df1[col].replace(...)` to directly index into the subset of `df2` corresponding to that question**. (This is simpler than using `.loc[]`)
3. A merge/join approach: right-join with `pd.merge(...)`

The 2. `.replace()` approach is simplest. So for example, we'll be using the following list to map the responses `df1['q1']` to 'q1' :

```
>>> df2.query("var == 'q1'").set_index('num')['val']
num
1      male
2    female
```

This works nice and cleanly indexing with `.loc[]`:

```
>>> df2.query("var == 'q1'").set_index('num')['val'] [2]
'female'
```

But `.replace()` is simpler than `.loc[]`:

```
>>> df1['q1'].replace( df2.query("var == 'q1'").set_index('num') ['val'] )
0      male
1      male
2    female
3    female
4      male
```

Then we can `pd.concat([...], axis=1)` the three subresults:

```
dout = [df1['q1'].replace(df2.query("var == 'q1'").set_index('num') ['val']),
        df1['q2_1'].replace(df2.query("var == 'q2'").set_index('num') ['val']),
        df1['q2_2'].replace(df2.query("var == 'q2'").set_index('num') ['val']) ]

pd.concat(dout, axis=1)

       q1   q2_1   q2_2
0    male    one    one
1    male    two    two
2  female  three  three
3  female  three  three
4    male    one  three
```

Finally you can fix up the index to the original 'id' column:

```
>>> pd.concat(dout, axis=1).set_index(df1['id'])
        q1   q2_1   q2_2
id                      
1     male    one    one
2     male    two    two
3   female  three  three
4   female  three  three
5     male    one  three
```

(PS you might want to do `df1.set_index('id')` right from the beginning. It makes things cleaner.)

3. The merge/join approach:

Looks like this:

```
>>> pd.merge( df1['q1'], df2.query("var == 'q1'").set_index('num') ['val'], left_on='q1', right_index=True, how='left', sort=False)

   q1     val
0   1    male
1   1    male
2   2  female
3   2  female
4   1    male
```

This was more annoying than the `.replace()` approach because I couldn't figure out how to easily prevent the 'q1' being passed to the output of the join.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important part of this response is to create a dictionary of categorical variables as its source. I have replaced the num column with an index, and replaced the grouping with a map function.

```
# dict create
df2.set_index('num', inplace=True)
df2 = df2.groupby('var').agg(dict)

df2
        val
var     
q1  {1: 'male', 2: 'female'}
q2  {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

# df update
df1['q1'] = df1['q1'].map(df2['val'][0])
df1['q2_1'] = df1['q2_1'].map(df2['val'][1])
df1['q2_2'] = df1['q2_2'].map(df2['val'][1])
```